# how to save an array with multiple items on each side of HABTM

Tags: php, database, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I want to import a bunch of Bookmarks, which have multiple Keywords each. Each Keyword can be connected to multiple Bookmarks as well.

The data comes in as JSON, which is parsed to PHP like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => example1
            [url] => http://example.org
            [keywords] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Hello
                    [1] => World
                )
        )
)
```

I then convert this into a CakePHP style array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Bookmark] => Array
                (
                    [title] => example1
                    [url] => http://example.org
                )

            [Keyword] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Hello
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => World
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

If I do a `$this->Bookmark->save($data)` it saves the Bookmark, and I can get the ID from the Bookmark from `$this->Bookmark->id`. But `$this->Keyword->saveAll($data)` does not do anything.

How can I save the Bookmark and connect all the keywords to it, without saving Keywords twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For saving the Bookmark data

```
$this->Bookmark->save($data['Bookmark'])
```

For saving the Keyword data

```
$this->Keyword->saveAll($data['Keyword'])
```

## Updated

,You should change ur array like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Bookmark] => Array
            (
                [title] => example1
                [url] => http://example.org
            )

 [Keyword] => Array
            (   
                [Keyword] => Array
                 (
                     [0] => Array
                         (
                                [title] => Hello
                         )

                     [1] => Array
                         (
                             [title] => World
                         )
                  )
             )
        )
   )
```

Comment: This does indeed save everything, but the Keywords are not associated with the Bookmark though.

Comment: hello i cant understand .now wts ur question.

Comment: The Bookmarks and the Keywords should be associated with their HABTM model. Your code only saves the Bookmark and the Keywords, but does not connect them.

Comment: This uses the IDs of the Keywords. I now just put the Keywords into the DB myself and add the IDs to the Bookmark. Works like a charm, but is not as magic as I expected.